# SQL Developer - No data shown when opening a table via UI

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer, when I try to see a specific table's data using "select * from [table]", I can see all data without any problems.

But when I try to open that same table in the graphical interface, using "Connections -> Tables -> right-click on [table] -> Open", I can open and see all tabs except "Data". When I try to open this tab, no data is populated on the screen and in "Messages - Log" appears the message "ORA-00906: Missing left parenthesis".

When checking the "Statements" window, I found out that SQL Developer creates the following query when I open the "Data" tab:

```
/* + NO_PARALLEL */SELECT ROWID "ROWID", ORA_ROWSCN "ORA_ROWSCN", name NAME, remarks REMARKS, xmlroot XMLROOT, FROM "ABC"."TABLE"
```

Since there is a column in that table called "xmlroot", the program confuses the column name with the xmlroot function.

Unfortunately I'm not allowed to change the column's name. Is there other thing I can do to correct this?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you select the "Statements" tab from the bottom of the section that currently shows you the "Messages - log" data, you can see "Statements - log" instead. From that can you identify the background statement that threw the error? Is there anything different about the table that sees this - does it have quoted identifiers, for instance? Adding the table definition to the question might be useful.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you! I updated the question.